# How to properly cancel a background worker that works forever?

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

Folks, I have a vb.net application in which I start a background worker when a button is pushed. The BGW works forever in a Do loop unless I push another button in which case it should be stopped, some other work performed and then the BGW started anew.

I have two versions of the code to date, based on research online, neither of which work though give differing results. Code so far is:

```
Dim autoEvent As New AutoResetEvent(False)
Private Sub StartWorkerButton_Click () Handles StartWorkerButton.Click
    MyWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    MyWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    MyWorker.RunWorker.Asunc()
End Sub

Private Sub MyWorker_ProgressChanged () Handles MyWorker.Progresschanged
    'Update some text boxes text string here based on data from the BGW work
End Sub

Private Sub StopThenRestartButton_Click Handles StopThenRestartButton.Click
    If MyWorker.IsBusy Then
        MyWorker.CancelAsync()
        autoEvent.WaitOne()
        ' Do some work here
        MyWorker.RunWorkerAsync() ' Restart BGW - But this fails!
    Else
        ' Do same work here but without stopping and restarting BGW
    End If
Exit Sub

Private Sub MyWorker_DoWork () Handles MyWorker.DoWork
    Do While 1
        If MyWorker.CancellationPending = True
            e.Cancel = True
            autoEvent.set
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ' Do some task work over and over again
            'ReportProgress() here as well
        End If
End Sub
```

Whichever way I work it it seems like execution can request the cancellation, set the event, but then will not restart the BGW because it seems to *still* be running. Gr.

Comment: If it really works `forever,` then there's nothing you can do;)

Comment: you should use `Exit While` instead of `Exit Sub` and move `autoEvent.set` to outside your while loop before `End Sub`.

Comment: You should probably have a boolean variable called `restartWorker` and if true, restart the worker in the RunWorkerCompleted event (check the e.Cancelled property).  It looks like you are just hoping the worker is done when you call RunWorkerAsync again in the StopThenRestart method.

Comment: @LarsTech I tried breakpointing in the completed event but it seems like it is never raised??

Comment: `autoEvent.set` clears your wait but the worker is still not finished. You should set it in RunWorkerCompleted Event

Comment: @bansi I also tried Exit Do at that point already with no luck... Cant get at the PC to try moving the autoEvent yet, will try that later

Comment: @bansi, please see my reply to LarsTech :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allow event processing on the main thread and also wait till the Worker finishes. Actually you don't need the `autoEvent`

```
Private Sub StopThenRestartButton_Click() Handles StopThenRestartButton.Click

    If MyWorker.IsBusy Then
        MyWorker.CancelAsync()
        autoEvent.WaitOne()
        While MyWorker.IsBusy
            'Process the events
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        ' Do some work here
        MyWorker.RunWorkerAsync() ' Restart BGW
    Else
        ' Do same work here but without stopping and restarting BGW
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is the code without `autoEvent`

```
Private Sub StartWorkerButton_Click() Handles StartWorkerButton.Click
    MyWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    MyWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    MyWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub MyWorker_ProgressChanged() Handles MyWorker.ProgressChanged
    'Update some text boxes text string here based on data from the BGW work
End Sub

Private Sub MyWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles MyWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    Console.WriteLine("RunWorkerCompleted Called")

End Sub


Private Sub StopThenRestartButton_Click() Handles StopThenRestartButton.Click
    If MyWorker.IsBusy Then
        MyWorker.CancelAsync()
        While MyWorker.IsBusy
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        Console.WriteLine("Worker Finished. Going to restart")

        ' Do some work here
        MyWorker.RunWorkerAsync() ' Restart BGW 
    Else
        ' Do same work here but without stopping and restarting BGW
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles MyWorker.DoWork
    Do While 1
        If MyWorker.CancellationPending = True Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Do ' Exit Sub also works here, if you have nothing to do after the loop
        Else
            ' Do some task work over and over again
            'ReportProgress() here as well
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` !! FTW